# Is it possible to show $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not metrizable without using the first countable definition and sequence lemma?

Tags: general-topology, metrizability, box-topology

I encountered a question about proving that $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, which is the countably infinite product of $\mathbb{R}$ under the product topology, is not metrizable. I have seen many solutions here by using the sequence lemma and the first countable argument, which is great. However, are there any ways to prove that by just using basic definitions of product topologies and metric spaces? I was trying to bring up some contradiction about violating the definition of being a metric but it seems nothing is wrong with that...

Comment: @user745578 wait, is it? I was reading this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737575/bbb-r-omega-in-the-box-topology-is-not-metrizable

Comment: That post talks about the box topology, while you ask about the product topology.

Comment: @MathQED Oh, I see. I was going for the wrong answer all the time.

Comment: No worries, it happens all of us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. A countable product of metrizable sets is metrizable (w.r.t. the product topology). In your case, $\Bbb{R}^\omega \cong \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$ is for example metrizable with metric

$$d((x_n)_n, (y_n)_n):= \sup_{n \in \Bbb{N}}\frac{1}{n} (|x_n-y_n| \land 1)$$

Comment: so we are dividing the distance between $x_n$ and $y_n$ by $n$?

Comment: I first make sure that the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$ becomes bounded: Indeed, replace $|x|$ by $|x| \land 1$. Check that the latter metric induces the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$ as well. And then yes, it gets divided by $n$.

Comment: Sorry, but I really need some definition clarification. In my knowledge, the basis of the product space is the set containing $\Pi_{i\in I} U_i = \{(x_i)\in \Pi_{i\in I}X_i|x_i \in U_i\}$ where each $U_i$ is open in $X_i$ and $\{i \in I| U_i \neq X_i\}$ is finite. And from wiki, I get something really similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology

What are the differences between them?

Comment: In one you don't allow infinitely many non-trivial factors in a basis and in the other you do.

Comment: Oh wow, such a small difference but totally different structure

Comment: @Ming [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362319/4280) I show that a countable product of metric spaces (in the *product topology*) is again metrisable, giving another, similar (and equivalent) metric for that product.